# Controller not found: service "AppBundle/Controller/TestController.php" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, debian

I get the error `Controller not found: service "AppBundle / Controller / TestController.php" does not exist`
but i don't know how to debug it. Can someone please help me !?
Is it possible that the error comes from the routing or it is something else !?
I just want to clarify that I use Symfony 3.4.

Here is the extract from the TestController.php code

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Task;
use AppBundle\Form\TaskType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("test/form-test")
 */
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="test")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // creates a task and gives it some dummy data for this example
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('addTask', TaskType::class, $task);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $validator = $this->get('validator');
        $errors = $validator->validate($form);
        if (count($editErrors) > 0) {
            $errorsString = (string)$editErrors;

            return new Response($errorsString);
        }
        echo('------------------------------------------------------------------------' . $form->isSubmitted() . ' && ' . $form->isValid());
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // $form->getData() holds the submitted values
            // but, the original `$task` variable has also been updated
            $task = $form->getData();

            // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
            // for example, if Task is a Doctrine entity, save it!
            // $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            // $entityManager->persist($task);
            // $entityManager->flush();
            return new Response('<h1>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------OK</h1>');
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'errors' => $errors,
        ]);
    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you add some related code to the question, what added code triggers the error? Does TestController exist? What did you try to do to debug yourselves?

Comment: it's already done.

Comment: You mean you solved it?

Comment: Not yet... But I've added code to my question. That's what I've done :p

Comment: I see! So the error occurs when you try to access "/test/form-test"? 
Is this Controller placed in the Controller directory? What is the output of:
php bin/console debug:container, can you find you controller service there?

Comment: When I run the command `php bin / console debug: container` I get the list of Controllers in" `AppBundle \ Controller` "and **TestController.php** is there.

Comment: Yes, I have the error above when I try to access the path `test / form-test`

Comment: Can you add the details of this output for TestController specific?

Comment: When I run the command `php bin/console debug:container 'AppBundle/Controller/TestController'` I have this result :                                              `Option           Value 
    Service ID     AppBundle\Controller\TestController
    Class             AppBundle\Controller\TestController
    Tags               controller.service_arguments
    Public             yes
    Synthetic        no
    Lazy               no
    Shared           yes
    Abstract         no
    Autowired             yes
    Autoconfigured        yes`

Comment: Is this a new Symfony 3.4 project? Maybe it is configured to map `src/` to the namespace `App\` rather than having an AppBundle?

Comment: can you remove the route annotation on the class "* @Route("test/form-test")" and use your homepage url "/" as defined above the controller action

Comment: and in file `routing.yml`, what should I put!?

Comment: this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-annotations